# Username is generated after update user informations

Tags: 8, users

in a drupal 8 project I've a problem with users usernames, when updating a user from BO and save change the username changed to be `email_registration_{a generated key}` this happen even with admin user (user with ID 1) the username was changed from `admin` to `email_registration_CFJffXsshq`

Any idea why the username is changed after an user update?

Thanks

**Update:**

The field `username` does not appear in user edit form and the contrib module `email_registration` is enabled.

How can I force printing the field `username` (field with label Display name) in user edit page?

**Fixed**

[This patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-01-28/email_registration-fix-random-usernames-3024558-10-D8.patch) fix the issue.
See [Strange username logic after rc6 release](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration/issues/3024558)

Comment: I'd bet it is due to the `email_registration` module and how it handles things.

Comment: when disabling email_registration module the field username is appear in user edit page, when enabling the module email_registration the field username disappear again and the field Display name (which should replace username) doesn't appear either. I need email_registration + field display name appear in user edit page.

Comment: Fixed by applying this patch: https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration/issues/3024558